# `window.XMLHttpRequest` is undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, window, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fix a javascript `window`-element problem. 
I've already did the classic:

- `npm install jQuery`
- `npm update`

Then, in 'server.js' file at line 1

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

On my Ubuntu this code works good, no problems, and the application goes ahead. On Windows 7 there is a monster i can't fight with.
Writing `node server.js` on my cmd (with Admin Rights), I see this msg:

[image]

I just couldn't take the reason of this: `window.XMLHttpRequest is undefined`. I am a curious person, so i discover where `window.XMLHttpRequest` is initialized and who/what works for this:

At line 8 of http://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery/blob/master/lib/node-jquery.js.

```
window.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

Why is not doing its job?
https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js here is the xmlhttprequest code.

Comment: welcome to the SO-community! please see my edit for further questions, formatting and stuff. feel free to enhance your own question but try to stick to our formatting-options - thanks!

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair thank you!

Comment: Did you correcttly install the module? (Your `XMLHttpRequest` polyfill is not prototype-based, by the way)

Comment: I guess so. I did `npm install xmlhttprequest` on cmd with no errors. Do i need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
- install python from 2.5.0 to 3.0.0 version (free)
- install Visual Express 2010 or later (free)

Answer (score 0):

you need to install xmlhttprequest module with npm :

```
    npm install xmlhttprequest
```

but normally, it is a browser only object, you should use that on the server :
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html

Comment: I just did it but there's nothing new. I know this is a browser object but is there another way to use jQuery on NodeJs without using `window` ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to manually patch your `node_module/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js` file!

Change these lines (around line 4 and 5)
from:

```
if(window == null ) {
    window = require('jsdom').jsdom().createWindow();
    ...
```

to:

```
if (!window || !window.document) {
    window = require('jsdom').createWindow();
    window.document = require('jsdom').jsdom();
    ...
```